# 3 monitors side by side, dropdowns & browser tab previews appear on adjacent monitor

Tags: windows-10

I have 3 monitors side by side, pic attached.

Any window opened on monitor #2 has an issue. Example: any browser opened full screen or even part, if you hover over tabs on the left half of the screen - previews appear where they supposed to - right under the tab.

But when you hover over tabs on the right side of the screen - previews appear on the adjacent monitor to the right #1 in the pic. And the more tab is to the right, the more to the right those previews appear on adjacent monitor.

Similar issue with dropdowns being used on monitor #2 -- in various programs.

Monitor #1 is the laptop.
Monitor #3 is set as main.

How to fix so that previews and dropdowns appear on the same screen, not on adjacent?

Thanks

[3M](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7692Z.png)

Comment: Are you in F7 --> Extend?

Comment: Elaborate please

Comment: I apologize. What mode are your monitors set in so that you can work simultaneously?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by mode... All three set to extend desktop, if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the laptop monitor to the same zoom level as the other two monitors solves the issue.
Of course, now it is at 100% as opposed to recommended 150%, so now everything on it is way too tiny.